# "Unexpected EOF" : How do I remove all newlines from php code?

Tags: php, javascript, regex

I have a php script that is reading a file in (file_get_contents). I want to replace all newlines with br's, and strip out all other characters. However, I am getting an error when interpreting the contents into a javascript variable.

I think the guilty party is the "^Z" character, but I don't know how to get rid of it. The "^M" is a git character, and I believe the "^Z" is actually part of the string itself.

How would I strip this character out in php?

[image]

---

Okay, my question was wrong before, so I have updated it with new content.

How do I ensure that all newlines are removed from a php string? This string is read in with file_get_contents, then javascript is dynamically created with the contents of the file. The "\n" is replaced with "NEW," and the "\r" is replaced with "".

However, I am getting an "Unexpected EOF" error, and when I copy the string and paste it into the console, something is giving me newlines. How do I make sure that ALL newlines (whitespace for that matter) is trimmed out?

`trim()`
`str_replace`
`preg_replace`

Have all been used, any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF]

Comment: ^Z is usually ctrl+z. it can signify End of File.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting the error message; it's an error in your code, not in your data, and it's about an unexpected program end, not about a literal ^Z character. Since apparently you have multiple layers of interpretation, and you post neither code nor the origin of the message, we have to guess.  My guess is you have a PHP syntax error. The premature EOF warning comes from code like `if (1) then` where at a minimum you have to close the block to fix the error.

Comment: Or if you are evaluating a single-quoted string which itself contains unescaped single quotes (for example), that could cause an "unexpected EOF" where the first unescaped quotes terminates the expression prematurely. The screenshot looks like there's something odd in the first argument to `JSON.parse()`, could that be it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> is the DOS/Windows end-of-file character for text files. If you examine your input file, you'll probably find that character in there.

It stems from the earliest days (CP/M no less) when files were an exact multiple of the disk sector size so you couldn't have files that weren't a multiple of that.

So, if you wanted to end the file earlier, you placed a special end-of-file character in there that the file reading routines would understand. This wasn't really a problem for binary files since it didn't matter if they had extraneous information at the end - it would most likely be ignored. However, you _didn't want any rubbish at the end of your nice little WordStar 3.3 document.

The `^Z` character is code number 26 so you *should* be able to use `str_replace` with the `\x1a` character, something like:

```
$str = str_replace ("\x1a", "", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, there is no such thing as a git character.

^M is code for a carriage return, it probably came from a windows machine that was working with the file.

^Z looks like it might be the "substitute" character which you can read about here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character, basically it means "I don't know how to represent the character in this spot"

That said, I see paxdiablo has posted just before me, and that code should do the trick. Good luck on your project!

Comment: I didn't mean git character as in 'a character git is adding to my files.' That is just the diff and it appears to show up wherever modifications occur whenever I say "git diff." I am no wstarting to believe it could be the problem though :)

Comment: Ah ok, what kind of OS are you on? And are you collaborating with anyone else on a different kind?

Comment: Yes, this is being compiled in windows. Ultimately, the php script is generating an HTML page and running it through wkhtmltopdf. I am dynamically generating JavaScript, and need wkhtmltopdf to execute that JS correctly (sorta ugly, I know, but a design decision I am stuck with for now)